# O alert do endpoint DELETE não funciona e quando deleta, volta para a página inicial ao invés de atualizar e continuar na mesma página

Tags: javascript, react, jsx

```js
const PlaylistComponent = (props) => {

    const[playlists, setPlaylists] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        getAllPlaylists()
    },[])

    const getAllPlaylists = () => {
        axios.get(BASE_URL, axiosConfig)
        .then(res=> setPlaylists(res.data.result.list))
        .catch((error) =>console.error(error))
    }

    const deletePlaylist = (playlistId) => {
        axios.delete(`${BASE_URL}/${playlistId}`, axiosConfig)
        .then(() => {
            alert('Playlist successfully deleted')
            getAllPlaylists()
            
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
    }

    const renderedPlaylist = playlists.map((playlist) => {
        return <PlaylistCard 
        
        key={playlist.id}
        playlistId={playlist.id}
        showPage={props.showPage}
        playlistName={playlist.name}
        deletePlaylist={deletePlaylist}
    
        />
       
    })

    return(
        <ListaPlaylistsContaniner>
            <h5>Lista de Playlists</h5>
            {renderedPlaylist}
        </ListaPlaylistsContaniner>
    )
};

export default PlaylistComponent;
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Tente adicionar um preventDefault antes da solicitação de exclusão.

```
const deletePlaylist = (playlistId, event) => {
    event.preventDefault() // adiciona essa linha
    axios.delete(`${BASE_URL}/${playlistId}`, axiosConfig)
    .then(() => {
        alert('Playlist successfully deleted')
        getAllPlaylists()
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))
}
```

No elemento Card no onClick do btn adicione isso:

```
<button onClick={(e) => deletePlaylist(playlist.playlistId, e)}>Excluir</button>
```